# Haproxy log format to mimic Common log format

Tags: logging, haproxy

I would like to have haproxy log access using the same format as most webservers default, CLF or also known as NCSA Common log format.

Does anyone have documentation for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I found that haproxy supports this with the clf option

```
defaults
   mode http
   option httplog clf
```

equivalent to:

```
log-format "%{+Q}o %{-Q}ci - - [%trg] %r %ST %B \"\" \"\" %cp \
            %ms %ft %b %s %TR %Tw %Tc %Tr %Ta %tsc %ac %fc \
            %bc %sc %rc %sq %bq %CC %CS %hrl %hsl"
```

and the source is
https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/observability/logging/log-formats/#clf-option

Comment: The word "Enterprise"  in the doc header confused me when I hit that page before you mention it in your answer :)